# Using a spinlock with c++ openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, spinlock

I have this method realised with a unique lock and a conditional variable. It adds an element into the array, but only if the array is not full. If full, it waits for other threads to take an element out and only then puts the new one in.

```
void Filter::put(Person person)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(lock);
    cv.wait(guard, [&] { return !full; });
    container[count] = person;
    count++;
    empty = false;
    if (count == 10)
        full = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

My goal is to write the same method using OpenMP. If I understand correctly, 
`#pragma omp critical (name)` should do the same thing as the unique lock. However, I am not sure how I should go about the spinlock.

Comment: What spinlock? Are you talking about the `cv.wait(...)` call? Awaiting a condition variable is not what people usually mean when they say "spin lock" because the thread does not use any CPU cycles while it is awaiting the condition var. (P.S., Sorry, I can't answer your question because I don't know OpenMP.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by it, sorry for not wording it correctly. I'm looking for a way to block the thread and unlock the critical section if the array is full and then continue the thread when there is space available using OpenMP.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if someone is interested, this is the solution I came up with after a bit of trial and error and it seems to be working okay.

```
void Filter::put(Person person)
{
    while (full || omp_test_lock(&spinlock) == 0)
    {
    }
    container[count] = person;
    count++;
    empty = false;
    if (count == 10)
        full = true;
    omp_unset_lock(&spinlock);
}
```

Comment: It is OK to self answer, but please do explain your code rather than providing a code dump. If you tell anybody with an interest in thread programming "and it seems to be working okay", then that should be enough to let them start worrying, if they won't go beserk, that is. Oh, and you want to lock / suspend threads, not loop them waiting for an answer, ever.